# django avatar custom template directory

Tags: python, django

I have a new problem with django avatar, can i change template base of django avatar in template custom on my project ?

my current template :

```html
{% extends "templates/base.html" %}
{% load i18n avatar_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Your current avatar :</p>
    {% avatar user %}
    {% if not avatars %}
        <p>{% trans "You haven't uploaded an avatar yet. Please upload one now." %}</p>
    {% else %}
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'avatar_change' %}">
            <ul>
                {{ primary_avatar_form.as_ul }}
            </ul>
            <p>{% csrf_token %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans "Choose new Default" %}" /></p>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'avatar_add' %}">
        {{ upload_avatar_form.as_p }}
        <p>{% csrf_token %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans "Upload New Image" %}" /></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I copy/paste the avatar template directory in my project and the change not work.

EDIT :
My Django version is 1.9.8

Is my settings.py :

```
""""
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- """ Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.8.

For more information on this file, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/ """

import os from django.core.mail import send_mail

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
# BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# print "base dir path :", BASE_DIR
# resultat du print => /home/cpoudevigne/Projets/MyMemoryBox/mysite

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret! SECRET_KEY = 'fywfd7s@e%36b_g@%!lt3o$t6i5g(&pfa8f9aa5#fhe@%7dzh('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production! DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Grappelli settings

GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = "My Title"

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'avatar',
    'registration',
    'mymemoryapp', ]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', ]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    }, ]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    } }

# Django-registration settings ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7 LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    }, ]

# Django-mail Settings

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' EMAIL_USE_TLS = True EMAIL_PORT = 587 EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' EMAIL_HOST_USER = '' EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '' DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ''

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/ PROJECT_DIR  = os.path.dirname(__file__) print "PROJECT_DIR :", PROJECT_DIR

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media') MEDIA_URL = '/media/' STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'mysite', 'static') STATIC_URL
= '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/'), ) print 'STATICFILES_DIRS :', STATICFILES_DIRS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to override `django-avatar`'s change page, you should place template you present in `<appname>/templates/avatar/change.html` or `<templates_dir>/avatar/change.html` if you have configured one.

Comment: I have placed the folder avatar in my app templates directory but not work.

Comment: What version of Django do you use? Also, please update your post with your `settings.py`.

Comment: Did you put your template in some app directory? If so, you should rearrange your `INSTALLED_APPS`, cause Django selects the first template it finds

Comment: I place avatar in INSTALLED_APPS before my app or after ?                   EDIT : i have placed avatar after my app and i work prefectly, a big thanks shhdup for your help ;)

Comment: You should place `avatar` **after** your app

Comment: Generally speaking, as far as I understand, the best practice for template overriding is: 1. create `template_overrides` directory in root of your project, 2. add this directory to `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` in your `settings.py` 3. Place the templates you want to override there.